# Tuning DAG/lineage graph in spark

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

we have a scenario like this:

we are fetching data from 10 RDBMS tables and converting them to dataframe's in spark.

joining all the dataframe's with different join criteria's and finally loading the final result to a table.

we are using multiple transformations to achieve the final query, so the DAG and lineage graph will be huge, can we optimize to make DAG/lineage graph smaller?

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: try considering checkpointing or cache

Comment: Can you quantify "huge"? Maybe after Spark optimizes and codegens your transformations its not going to be as scary as you expect?